# Receiving sms in android (APP Crash)

Tags: android, crash, sms

I am trying to understand how to receive SMS and get its contents in android.
No matter which example I try, including many from stack exchange, every time, my app crashes on receiving the sms. I am not able to find what I am doing wrong. Need help here.

Code :

```
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.telephony.SmsMessage;
import android.util.Log;


public class MySMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Object[] pdus=(Object[])intent.getExtras().get("pdus");
        SmsMessage shortMessage=SmsMessage.createFromPdu((byte[]) pdus[0]);
        Log.d("SMSReceiver","SMS message sender: "+
           shortMessage.getOriginatingAddress());
        Log.d("SMSReceiver","SMS message text: "+
           shortMessage.getDisplayMessageBody());
    }

}
```

Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.smstestbed"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_SMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_SMS" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.example.smstestbed.MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <receiver android:name=".MySMSReceiver"> 
            <intent-filter> 
                <action android:name="android.provider.Telephony.SMS_RECEIVED" /> 
            </intent-filter> 
        </receiver> 

    </application>


</manifest>
```

Logcat:

```
08-17 17:41:28.762: E/Trace(2647): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
08-17 17:41:29.612: D/libEGL(2647): loaded /system/lib/egl/libEGL_emulation.so
08-17 17:41:29.622: D/(2647): HostConnection::get() New Host Connection established 0x2a174ab8, tid 2647
08-17 17:41:29.622: D/libEGL(2647): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv1_CM_emulation.so
08-17 17:41:29.632: D/libEGL(2647): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLESv2_emulation.so
08-17 17:41:29.682: W/EGL_emulation(2647): eglSurfaceAttrib not implemented
08-17 17:41:29.692: D/OpenGLRenderer(2647): Enabling debug mode 0
08-17 17:42:06.712: D/AndroidRuntime(2647): Shutting down VM
08-17 17:42:06.712: W/dalvikvm(2647): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a71930)
08-17 17:42:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2647): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-17 17:42:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2647): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.smstestbed.MySMSReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.smstestbed.MySMSReceiver" on path: /data/app/com.example.smstestbed-1.apk
08-17 17:42:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2357)
08-17 17:42:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1500(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-17 17:42:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1310)
08-17 17:42:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-17 17:42:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-17 17:42:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-17 17:42:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-17 17:42:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-17 17:42:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-17 17:42:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-17 17:42:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-17 17:42:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2647): Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.smstestbed.MySMSReceiver" on path: /data/app/com.example.smstestbed-1.apk
08-17 17:42:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:65)
08-17 17:42:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:501)
08-17 17:42:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:461)
08-17 17:42:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:2352)
08-17 17:42:06.762: E/AndroidRuntime(2647):     ... 10 more
```

Thanks in advance.

Regards
Priyabrata

Comment: Logcat added to main post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your receiver class `MySMSReceiver` is most likely not in package `com.example.smstestbed`. So move the receiver class into  sub folders `com\example\smstestbed\`and add a ...

```
package com.example.smstestbed;
import android.content.BroadcastReceiver;
...

public class MySMSReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    ....
```

package declaration to your receiver class.

Comment: Mmmmhh, have you tried to clean the project after these changes? The package declaration doesn't show you an error and looks like above?

Comment: No, I had two sources in two different packages. I brought it into a single package, and now the app doesn't crash any more, but how-ever doesn't seem to respond to the reception of an sms either..

Comment: @Trinion : Problem has been resolved. The packages was the source of the trouble.